# Unable to start spring boot with spring cloud kinesis stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

Spring boot application fails during start. It looks like dependency issue but can't figure out what is missing.

pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    ....
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Code to consume messages

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
@Controller
class ConsumerTest {


    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void handle(@NotNull final Object object) {
        System.out.println("inside");
    }
}
```

yml file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: test
          content-type: application/json
        output:
          destination: test
          content-type: application/json
      kinesis:
        binder:
          auto-create-stream: false
```

And the exception is

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.test.spark.javaspark.JavasparkApplication.main(JavasparkApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:291) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:337) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:92) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:254) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kinesis.config.KinesisBinderConfiguration
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:392) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:317) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/stream/config/ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer

Your Spring Cloud Stream version is too old; that class was not added until 3.0 (Horsham), which requires Boot 2.2.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#overview

Comment: I updated spring-cloud-stream to 3.0.0 and spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.2.1 and it works now.